# Does IE6 support any HTML5 elements?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-6, browser-support

Does IE6 support any HTML5 elements?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<header>
<section>
<header>
<nav>
<canvas>
<video>
```

Comment: @Kragen - aren't you making an assumption about the OP's intention with that edit? maybe he didnt mean "new" elements - like in @Chuck's answer.

Comment: @RPM @Marko they were in the original question, just not visible (click view source in revision history)

Comment: actually yeah ive noticed that problem with SO - it doesnt like xml in "code blocks". bizarre.

Comment: well visit here to check the support of html5 in detail to various browsers. http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie06.html

Comment: It actually supports a single obscure purely HTML5 element. See my answer below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It barely supports HTML4.... ha :)

No it doesn't without some fancy Javascript HTML5 *emulating* script type-of-thing.

**Edit**

Such as [this one](http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/).

Comment: ie6 supports iframe, which landed in html5 spec. so that's one. there are many more, just nothing a marketing executive would label as "html5"

Comment: IE6 4 HTML1 ha :)

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what you mean by "HTML5 elements." In that most tags commonly used on the Web are included as part of HTML5, yes, it supports the vast majority of HTML5.

If you mean new elements introduced in HTML5 that had never been used before, no, it supports none of them, because HTML 4 was cutting-edge when IE6's HTML parser was created.

Comment: @Marko That's **really** not what this question is about. This question is about native support, not polyfills.

Answer (score 5):

No it doesn't, but you can still use HTML 5 elements and style them using CSS by using Modernizr http://www.modernizr.com/

This will also add classes to the html element describing what functionality is available in the current browser.

Comment: That's really not what this question is about. This question is about native support, not polyfills.

Comment: The answer regarding native support is given quite clearly in the first three words.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **no**. =)

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html5.html

Answer (score 3):

It does in the same way that all other versions of IE < 9 do, if you use the html5 shiv script. My site is in HTML5 and works fine in IE6, althoguh slightly differently. Sure if you turn off JavaScript it won't work, but if you're using IE6 and you have JavaScript turned off I'm afraid I'm not that worried about you as you're such a minority.

Comment: That's really not what this question is about. This question is about native support, not polyfills.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, (surprise, surprise!) [IE5.5 implemented this ruby tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby#compat-desktop) element that was originally defined in the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-ruby-element), and not one peep  or reference to any ruby element in the [HTML4 specification,](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/).

Wow Microsoft! You really know how to waste your resources creating an obscure HTML5 tag instead of fixing the broken box model, let alone trying to better support even HTML4, let alone trying to fix the hundreds of thousands of security breaches. Just wow!

Answer (score 1):

Ha ha yeah right. IE6 gives enough grief with HTML 4 as well as CSS, let alone HTML 5. Which is a shame if you are wanting to use HTML5 but have to make your website compatible with IE6 due to the client (where I work they often use IE5...I don't even want to go there).

Comment: Oh, my sympathies. Lemme guess, health care?

Comment: Nope. Surprisingly an electrical components distributor. I know right. Well, the sub-manager I get my tasks from uses Mozilla. ;) And he let me install Google Chrome.

Comment: That's the grand secret in a lot of organizations I think. They think they're using IE5 or 6, but then you look at what people use, and it's FF or Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

No. Only because of the 15 character limit, let me add, if you want to use HTML 5 I would not recommend worrying about IE6 compatibility. The workarounds and hacks etc. you need to use to make things look the same on IE6 as they would on any modern browser are not worth the time.

The great thing about HTML+CSS is that it can degrade gracefully. Practice on that, and you can create a site that is wonderful on a modern browser, and on IE 6 looks nice, functions, and does not give the appearance of being "broken" or "missing" anything, even though it won't have the fancy stuff other people are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fake tags using javascript:

Creating the new elements with JavaScript

Working in jQuery is cool and all, but as it turns out, there is a built in function to JavaScript to deal with creating new elements:

```
document.createElement('header');
document.createElement('footer');
document.createElement('section');
document.createElement('aside');
document.createElement('nav');
document.createElement('article');
document.createElement('figure');
document.createElement('time');
```

Comment: This is such a weird answer! Passive-aggressive against jQuery? :) And jQuery can only do what Javascript can do, so no surprises there.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 6 not support **header** / **section** / **nav** / **canvas** / **video** tag ( **header** / **section** / **nav** / **canvas** / **video** tag support in Internet Explorer 9 and more ).

Credit link : [one](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp) , [two](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp) , [three](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_canvas.asp) , [four](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp) and [five](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_section.asp).